# How to find out the max size of a image disk file created by kvm-img?

Tags: linux, linux-kvm

I created a VM disk image with kvm-img, but I forget what was the max size of that disk image when I created it. Currently, its size is 6.2G, I want to install some large packages in that VM, so I want to make sure the disk image can expand to an adequate size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `kvm-img info <filename>`.